# PHP and socket.io connection

Tags: php, socket.io, phpwebsocket

I need to keep persistent PHP and socket.io connection. PHP script should serve as client (listen for socket.io events and emit back to socket.io). Is it even possible? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/) for it.

> Ratchet is a loosely coupled PHP library providing developers with
>   tools to create real time, bi-directional applications between clients
>   and servers over WebSockets. This is not your Grandfather's Internet